# Python "Invalid Syntax Error" With Regular Expression for Phone

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a phone regex, based on [a pattern provided in another stack overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123666/773210)

This is the syntax I used to create it in Python:

```
def phoneRegex = r'^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$'
```

However, when running this code I get the error:

```
^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to escape the characters somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the `def` statement. Take it out. You use `def` to define functions. That's not a function, that's an assignment of a string.